# Who designs the different Stack Exchange site logos?

Tags: discussion, design, images, logo

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this but my motivation for asking this question is the beautiful logo for Aviation Stack Exchange. It is super memorable and I would love to know who designed it.

Is there some place the creator of these logos is documented?

Comment: Most of them were designed by [Jin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin), although he no longer works at Stack.

Comment: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/new-site-design

Comment: Although it [looks like](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3008/19381) the Aviation theme was designed by Stéphane.

Comment: Whom is also no longer with SE, by the looks of it at least since '17

Comment: The tags [design and discussion](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdesign%5D+and+%5Bdiscussion%5D) often turn up results detailing the process on each site. Occasionally the users do most of the work, often it is tweaked by various employees (over the years) to fit overall site design. A couple of years ago many sites were completely different and some fully customized, more recently that was unified; with some elements shared amongst all the sites. Various people undertake the task, you need to check each site's meta (unfortunately).